# Forest with ranger predictions on non-continuous data

Tags: r, random-forest, mnist, r-ranger

I'm creating a random forest model with ranger in R that training on MNIST pixel data and predicting the number that the pixels represent (0-9). After creating my model with the following code and looking at the predictions, many of my predicted numbers are continuous (decimals).

```
set.seed(1031)
forestranger <- ranger(Y ~ ., data = mnisttrain, num.trees = 1000)
predictions <- predict(forestranger, data = mnisttest, num.trees = 1000)
```

Is there a way to ensure my predictions are only a whole number between 0 and 9 and not continuous?

Answer (score 0):

Converting the response variable to a factor seems to have solved the issue